# Setting an associated attribute to nil when a validation fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

On a form submit, if a validation fails, I would like to set the associated attribute to nil. Is there an easy way to do this in rails? I would think a method exist but I am having trouble finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
after_validation :remove_bad_attributes 

def  remove_bad_attributes
    if errors.any?
        errors.keys.each do |err|
            assign_attributes(err => nil)
        end
    end
end
```

The above worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an after_validation callback...

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_validation :set_failed_attributes_to_nil

  def set_failed_attributes_to_nil
    errors.messages.each { |k, _| write_attribute(k, nil) }
  end

end
```